# Formatting time with strptime when some times are missing and convert AM/PM to 24 hour format

Tags: r, datetime, format, converters

I have a timestamp vector like

```
time_stamp <- c("7/1/2013", "7/1/2013 12:00:30 AM", "7/1/2013 12:01:00 AM", "7/1/2013 12:01:30 AM", "8/1/2013","8/1/2013 11:02:30 PM")
```

I want to format this to date class. I tried

```
strptime(time_stamp, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")
```

but since two timestamps have missing times it results in `NA`s, which should be substituted by default: 12:00:00.

I can run a loop such as:

```
for (i in 1:length(time_stamp))
{
   if(nchar(time_stamp[i])<11)
   {
       time_stamp[i] <- paste(time_stamp[i], " 12:00:00 AM")
    }
}

time_stamp <- format(strptime(time_stamp, format = "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz = "GMT"), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")
```

Is there a faster and cleaner way to accomplish this? The vector is a part of large dataset so I don't want to loop over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use a bit of regex replacement and then process as normal:

```
as.POSIXct(sub("(\\d{4}$)", "\\1 00:00:00", time_stamp),
           format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")
#[1] "2013-01-07 00:00:00 GMT" "2013-01-07 12:00:30 GMT" "2013-01-07 12:01:00 GMT"
#[4] "2013-01-07 12:01:30 GMT" "2013-01-08 00:00:00 GMT" "2013-01-08 11:02:30 GMT"
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain the regex used in the context.

Comment: @discipulus - it essentially just replaces the last 4 digits representing the year `d{4}` at the end of the text `$` with the 4 digits `\\1` plus `00:00:00`

Answer (score 3):

`lubridate::parse_date_time` can take multiple token orders, with or without the `%`:

```
lubridate::parse_date_time(time_stamp, orders = c("dmy IMS p", "dmy"))
## [1] "2013-01-07 00:00:00 UTC" "2013-01-07 00:00:30 UTC" "2013-01-07 00:01:00 UTC"
## [4] "2013-01-07 00:01:30 UTC" "2013-01-08 00:00:00 UTC" "2013-01-08 23:02:30 UTC"
```

Or use its `truncated` parameter:

```
lubridate::parse_date_time(time_stamp, orders = 'dmy IMS p', truncated = 4)
```

which returns the same thing.